# Germany: Does a github.io hosted site require imprint / data privacy statement according to the GDPR?

Tags: privacy, germany, gdpr, data-protection

github offers free publicly accessible data storage. Many people use that to present their personal profile where they e.g. advertise for freelancing services. An example url could be http://username.github.io.

If I have such a personal page where I advertise services, do I need to make sure I have an [Impressum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressum) and a data privacy statement to comply with the new General Data Protection Regulation [DSGVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)?

It would be hosted by github and linked to and accessible only via github, not e.g. a domain of mine. Though it would still be possible to e.g. include a contact form that sends visitor data to my email address.

Comment: Would the gdpr tag be a better match for this question than some of the current tags?

Comment: The imprint would always have been required, it has nothing to do with DSGVO, no? Shouldn’t matter who the webhost is, nor under which URL the site is accessible.

Comment: Note that "imprint" is not a good translation for the "Impressum" required by German law. The "Impressum" for websites is legal duty that does not exist in most English-speaking countries, hence there is no English word for it. I edited to change the term to "Impressum".

Comment: Please split it in two questions. You are interested in a) Do I need an impressum?  b) Do I need a Datenschutzerklärung according to the DSGVO/GDPR? For (a) see also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28459/do-github-projects-by-germans-require-an-imprint-link-in-their-readme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a few quick notes that come to mind. As the commenters point out:

- DSGVO is indeed the German equivalent name to the GDPR (English term)
- "Imprint" isn't a privacy related topic that much, as such it's not really changed by the upcoming GDPR
- The GDPR changes many things, but the requirement for up front information isn't one of them - so it would've already been a rule to follow

Sometimes the question who is responsible for privacy information might not be that easy to decide when you're on platforms. I take this situation as being pretty clear though. You are basically given a blank slate, you can do with that page whatever you want, and the visitor has no clue whatsoever that it might be hosted by Github. 
In addition to this, Github would be classified as a data processor (providing the tool) and you as the data controller who is in charge of practically everything except for the provision of the page.

I hope this helps. Btw. it's not that hard anymore to write a privacy policy these days.